# How to say: "at three different sides of the room "

Tags: translation

I want to tell a joke where the teacher places three students at three different sides of the room. I tried like this, but apparently it was wrong:

> 老師讓他們分散在房間的三方。

Can you offer any suggestions? Also things like "place them apart from each other " might help.

Comment: one suggestion：在房间的三个边，  把他们相互（彼此）分开相隔较远

Comment: Where's the joke? I like jokes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the teacher places three students at three different sides of the room：

老师让三个学生分别站在房间三面墙前。